# Can I add a textnode instead of an attribute in a .NET configurationsection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config

I currently have a .NET custom configurationsection that looks like this:

```
<customSection name="My section" />
```

What I want is to write it as a textnode (I'm not sure if this is the correct term?) like this:

```
<customSection>
  <name>My Section</name>
</customSection>
```

My current customSection class looks like this:

```
public class CustomSection: ConfigurationSection {

  [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
  public String Name {
    get {
      return (String)this["name"];
    }
  }

}
```

What should I do to make it a textnode?

Comment: Why in the world didn't Microsoft allow this in the first place?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A bit of research suggests that the existing configuration classes do not support that type of element without creating a custom class to handle it. [This CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ConfigurationTextElement.aspx) article covers creating a new `ConfigurationTextElement` class that is generic and can parse a serialized string into an object (including a string, which is what the article shows).

The class code is brief:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;

public class ConfigurationTextElement<T> : ConfigurationElement
{
    private T _value;
    protected override void DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, 
                            bool serializeCollectionKey)
    {
        _value = (T)reader.ReadElementContentAs(typeof(T), null);
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to be able to have both attributes as well as text content e.g.

```
<customsection>
      <name key="val">My Section</name>
</customSection>
```

Then you can override `DeserializeElement` like so:

```
protected override void DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, bool serializeCollectionKey)
{
    int count = reader.AttributeCount;
    //First get the attributes
    string attrName;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
        attrName = reader.Name;
        this[attrName] = reader.Value;
    }
    //then get the text content
    reader.MoveToElement();
    text = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was very helpful, but leaves me wondering why applying a .NET configuration file to objects is such a huge chore.  Compare this to JAXB unmarshal from Xml to Object, where if you define an object with obviously named properties, you don't have to code *anything*.  Given the elegance and LINQ, the lambdas, and ExpressionTree parts of the API, I'm shocked at how primitive the Object model for the ConfigurationManager is (and also by how much code it takes to apply the configuration to objects.)  Is there anything more updated?

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work on an element that has more child elements, without any success. Are you able to show how you can do that?