# Why can't I convert attribute to nested element?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

I'm reading settings from 'App.config'. I just figured out how to work with `ConfigurationSection`, `ConfigurationElementCollection` and `ConfigurationelElement`.

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration> 
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="notificationSettingsGroup">
                <section name="mailTemplates" type="Project.Lib.Configuration.MailTemplateSection, Project.Lib"
                    allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>         
    </configSections>
    <notificationSettingsGroup>
        <mailTemplates>
            <items>
                <mailTemplate name="actionChain" subject="Subject bla-bla">
                    <body>Body bla-bla</body>
                </mailTemplate>                 
            </items>
        </mailTemplates>
    </notificationSettingsGroup>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>  
</configuration>
```

My C# code:

```
public class MailTemplateSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("items", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    public MailTemplateCollection MailTemplates
    {
        get { return (MailTemplateCollection)this["items"]; }
        set { this["items"] = value; }
    }
}
```

---

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MailTemplateElement), AddItemName = "mailTemplate",
    CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap)]
public class MailTemplateCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new MailTemplateElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((MailTemplateElement) element).Name;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MailTemplateElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "action", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("subject", DefaultValue = "Subject", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Subject
    {
        get { return (string)this["subject"]; }
        set { this["subject"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("body", DefaultValue = "Body", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Body
    {
        get { return (string)this["body"]; }
        set { this["body"] = value; }
    }
}
```

---

And working code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Configuration config =
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
            ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        var mailTemplatesSection =
           config.GetSection("notificationSettingsGroup/mailTemplates") as MailTemplateSection;

    }
}
```

All works, when I'm declaring fields as attributes in xml. But when I try to convert attributes into nested element - *"Property 'Body' is not a ConfigurationElement"* error occurs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Refer this [how to use text element instead of attribute in custom configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078758/can-i-add-a-textnode-instead-of-an-attribute-in-a-net-configurationsection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have to create custom types and derive them from ConfigurationElement in order to use them as elements in config file. All simple types are always written as attributes.
For example:

```
public class Body : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("value", DefaultValue = "Body", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Value{get;set;}
}
```

This will allow you to write

```
<body value="some val"/>
```

in your config.

Comment: Vladimir, I want to store _large text_ in "body" attribute, then don't want store this data in attribute. IMHO, large data must be stored inside tags.

Comment: Large texts should not be stored in App.config at all. Use either database, or custom format. It may easily be an XmlSerializer generated format, for which you can create classes and fully control how your data is serialized.

Comment: So frustrating, how many time people do not respond to the original request, arguing that this is not the way to go. In this case, there could be plenty of reasons to use an element instead of an attribute, like using CDATA…